# vault token - not able to pass option for requested/custom TTL

Tags: api, postman, ttl

Reading through vaults documentation for ldap auth [method](https://www.vaultproject.io/api/auth/ldap/index.html), I am able to successfully login via a postman API call to the vault server.

ldap is currently configured with default-lease of 3600s(1hr) and max-lease 86400(s). In postman calling, I provide password and ttl KVs. however the response, while successful, still comes back with the default 1hr lease for my token.

```
{
  "password": "mypassword",
  "lease_duration": "5" 
}
```